# Tomcat 7 : exlcude a jar from a war I did not package

Tags: tomcat, jar, log4j, tomcat7, war

I do have a Tomcat 7 on which I have an app running. On this tomcat, in the tomcat/lib folder, there is a jar *log4j-over-slf4j.jar* which is used by the app.

Now I am trying to deploy a webapp which I did not code or build (more precisely [Hawtio](https://hawt.io/docs/get-started/#deploying-on-a-servlet-container)) by simply dropping the war of that application in the tomcat/webapp folder. However, Hawtio is using *slf4j-log4j12.jar* and a conflict of [delegation loop](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop) appears between the two jars and it raises an exception, preventing Hawtio from starting.

I have tried removing the *log4j-over-slf4j.jar* from the tomcat/lib folder and it works, but I would prefer not doing so to avoid having any regression. Is there any way to exclude jars stored in the tomcat/lib folder from the war deployment ?

Answer (score 0):

update your pom.xml to exclude the slf4j file

review your maven dependencies and see which one(s) use slf4j and may be including it in the war file.  Then add this to each of those

```
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
```

You'll need to wrap the above with  if you don't have any other exclusions for the particular dependency.